# XSLT logic to choose between values if present

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I need to write XSLT logic to choose between different elements based on the presence.  For example

```
<Box>
    <Thing>
        <Title>Toy</Title>
        <Value>1</Value>
    </Thing>
    <Thing>
        <Title>Towel</Title>
        <Value>2</Value>
    </Thing>
</Box>
```

If a "thing" with a title "Towel" is present the value of "Box" becomes 2.  If 'Towel' is not present it chooses the "thing" with title 'Toy' and the value of "Box" becomes 1.

So the output from above would be

```
<Box>
    2
</Box>
```

Where the output of

```
<Box>
    <Thing>
        <Title>Toy</Title>
        <Value>1</Value>
    </Thing>
</Box>
```

would be

```
<Box>
    1
</Box>
```

The "things" can come in any order though, so

```
<Box>
    <Thing>
        <Title>Towel</Title>
        <Value>2</Value>
    </Thing>
    <Thing>
        <Title>Toy</Title>
        <Value>1</Value>
    </Thing>
</Box>
```

would still have the output of

```
<Box>
    2
</Box>
```

because Towel gets picked over Toy if it is present
My thought is I need to do a for-each loop but I am really quite lost.

Thanks

Comment: Please show us the XML result you want to create, I don't think saying  "the value of Box becomes" is a good way to explain which output you want to create. And I don't see any `objectA` or `objectB` elements, that part is also not clear.

Answer (score 1):

I would match on `Box` and populate it with the desired value, either by putting the conditions in different templates with the desired priority

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Box[Thing/Title = 'Towel']" priority="5">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="Thing[Title = 'Towel']/Value"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Box[Thing/Title = 'Toy']">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="Thing[Title = 'Toy']/Value"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4HL/0, https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4HL/1 and https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4HL/2 for your examples.

Or you could use a single template and  `xsl:choose/xsl:when` tests inside.

For both approaches it is not clear what you want to do if your both conditions are not met or what is supposed to happen with the other elements in the input. But adapting the identity transformation template or, if there is only that `Box` element, removing it and using the template(s) matching `Box` should solve the transformation for those elements.

Comment: Trying to understand, why is priority="5" needed on the template?

Comment: @Sebastien, the question seems to want to put priority on the condition/check `Thing/Title = 'Towel'` used in that template over the other condition `Thing/Title = 'Toy'`. So I explicitly put a priority value on the template, the number 5 is kind of arbitrary, it just needs to be higher than any of the default priorities and perhaps leave some room to write more templates for other conditions with priorities between the default and the highest one.